# Ruby TK Download

Tags: ruby

```
require 'tk'
root = TkRoot.new { title "Hello world" }
TkLabel.new(root) do
text 'Hello world!'
end
Tk.mainloop
```

Where can i download Ruby TK? i googled but didnt find it.

Answer (score 1):

On linux it is contained in the **libtcltk-ruby** package.

```
sudo apt-get install libtcltk-ruby
```

On windows, the bindings are included with the one-click ruby installer.

-John

Comment: apt-get is only for Debian based systems, other distributions will use other package management systems.

Comment: With a question this basic it's safe to assume he isn't using a distro futher than Ubuntu.

Comment: Well if hes using OS X it comes preinstalled.

Comment: Or, you could just add `yum install libtcltk-ruby` and rest assured that one of these two will do the job for him.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS X, using homebrew:

```
brew install --with-tcltk ruby
```

If this command results in a message that ruby is already installed, and if `require 'tk'` fails, then `brew uninstall ruby`.